VBA how do i count Json objects in an array in excel vba

I have the above Json response in my VBA code.
I want to count the number of "dangerous" items within defects within motTests.
I have tried Json("motTests")(2)("defects").count but the result is 3 which is the number if items within "defects" how can I count the number of occurences of "dangerous" within "defects" . hope this makes sense and any help appreciated. Thanks

As there is no build-In Json parser in VBA, you are probably using one of the tools that are out there. You should tell us which tool you use and show the relevant piece of code. Also, don't post your data as Image, try to post it as text (format it as code, maybe limit it to a relevant piece) so that someone can work with it when trying to give an answer.

Loop over the defects and count those where "dangerous" is True.
